# How do you use the Left/right/substitute functions to find values inbetween commas

Tags: excel, excel-formula

ie: Messenger, **5**, **8.5** - Facebook < 1.2B >

I need to pull out the 5 in between the two commas and the 8.5 in between the "," & "-"
The function has to allow for more decimals ie: DoorDash, **6.2**, **2.7** - DoorDash < 4.9M >

I was doing `=IFERROR(TRIM(MID(A4,SEARCH(",",A4)+1,SEARCH("-",A4)-SEARCH(",",A4)-1)),"")` but the output I keep getting is `5, 5.8 –` and I cannot seem to separate the two.

Other:
There are only two commas in what is given and all of the given ones follow the same structure (text, number , number - text < number >). Need to use the formulas left, right, mid, search, rept, find, switch, or text

I need two formulas: one to find the **5** and the other to find the **5.8**

Comment: I was doing 
=IFERROR(TRIM(MID(A4,SEARCH(",",A4)+1,SEARCH("-",A4)-SEARCH(",",A4)-1)),"")
 but the output I keep getting is 5, 5.8

Comment: Is it always just two comma? or can there be more or less?

Comment: Your formula in your comment works on your two examples for me. ```5, 8.5``` and ```6.2, 2.7```

Comment: I need it to display both answers in two different cells. Where one cell give me 5 and the other cell gives me 8.5 @Brian

Comment: @ScottCraner they always contain 2 commas

Answer (score 1):

Use FILTERXML:

```
=INDEX(FILTERXML("<z>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A1,"<",""),">",""),"-","</y>"),",","</y><y>",2),",","<y>")&"</z>","//y"),COLUMN(A1))
```

Put that in the first cell changing only the `$A1` reference to the cell reference leaving the other `A1` as it is.

Depending on one's version of Excel this may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Then copy over and down the data set.

[image]

Comment: Do suggest any other ways to do it without using FILTERXML?

Comment: I will let someone else do that.

Answer (score 1):

Or............

In `B1`, formula copied across right

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(9^9,0+MID($A1,SEARCH("@",SUBSTITUTE($A1,",","@",COLUMN(A1)))+2,ROW($A$1:$A$9))),"")
```

[image]